# JSON Object Not Posting

Tags: php, android, json, gson

I am trying to Post a JSON object using the code below:

```
       public void postABeer(final int beerId, final Handler h) {

        new Thread (myThreadGroup, new Runnable () {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                BeerAdapter ba = new BeerAdapter();
                Beer newBeer = new Beer();
                newBeer = ba.createBeer("{\"ID\":\"973\", \"Name\":\"Beer\", \"Price\":\"4.99\", \"Comment\":\"bla\", \"LastModified\":\"196\"}");

                //Do background stuff here.
                String s = HttpHandler.HttpPostExec(MainActivity.baseURI
                        + "beer/" + beerId, newBeer.toString());

                //Start of artificial delay.Comment out if not wanted.
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //End of artificial delay.

                Message m = new Message();
                m.obj = s;
                h.sendMessage(m);

            }//end run()

        }).start();

    }//end postABeer()

}//end BackGroundBinder class
```

Below is code in my HTTP Handler:

```
public static final String HttpPostExec (String uri, String payload) {

    String s = "no response";
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    int http_status = 0;

    try {
        byte[] payloadBytes = payload.getBytes();
        URL url = new URL(uri);

        conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); //We be doing a POST
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); //We are sending JSON
        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(payloadBytes.length);

        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();

        out.write(payloadBytes);

        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
        http_status = conn.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println("hey");


        if (http_status == 200) {
            s = streamToString(in);
        } else {
            s = "bad response";
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException m) {
        s = "malformed URL exception";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        s = e.toString();
    } finally {
        conn.disconnect();
    }
    return s;

}
```

When I execute 'postABeer', the following Error message is displayed:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:wirelessward.net/beer/gateway.php/beer/973

Here is my beer class also:

```
    private String ID, Name, Price, Comment, LastModified;

public Beer() {
}

public Beer(String ID, String name, String price, String comment, String lastModified) {
    this.ID = ID;
    Name = name;
    Price = price;
    Comment = comment;
    LastModified = lastModified;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Beer{" +
            "ID='" + ID + '\'' +
            ", Name='" + Name + '\'' +
            ", Price='" + Price + '\'' +
            ", Comment='" + Comment + '\'' +
            ", LastModified='" + LastModified + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Study about [Volley Request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html,).

```
final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```